# Sublime Text 3.2.1: How do I get rid of these popups as I type?

Tags: sublimetext3

[The popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjINO.png) give context help on whatever I am typing. I find them distracting and they often obscure code I am looking at while I type.

These are my current Sublime Text (syntax specific) settings:

```
// These settings override both User and Default settings for the JSON syntax
{
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "show_definitions": false,
    "auto_complete_delay": 100,
    "open_files_in_new_window": false,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": true,
}
```

Comment: Are you using anaconda?

Comment: Fairly sure these are called tooltips if that may help your searching.

Answer (score 1):

Add these to the settings

```
"enable_signatures_tooltip": false,
"enable_docstrings_tooltip": false
```